How to get the score of incertitude of a document?
I have a crf model (sklearn_crfsuite) that I use to label named entities. I'd like to train my model with the documents that are the most complex for my model (active learning principle).
To do this, I'm using the predict_marginals function, which allows me to return lists of probabilities for each token in each of my documents. Intuitively, I want to average the maximum probability of each token (since we have a probability for each available tag) to obtain a score for my document. But I realize that this isn't necessarily the best way to go about it.
In that case, I was wondering if you had any advice or ways of doing things to obtain an uncertainty score for each of my documents?
